# I want to check every row of a mysql table for a specific value of a field by php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySql table. 
I want to check its specific field in all the rows. If this field has a specific value in any of the rows, I want PHP to print something and if any of the row doesn't have that value, then I want PHP to do something else.

look at this code:

```
$queryplus="SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id='$id' and comment='plus'";
$resultplus=mysql_query($queryplus) or die(mysql_error());
while($rowplus = mysql_fetch_array($resultplus))
{
    $email3=$rowplus['email'];
    $fname3=$rowplus['fname'];
    $lname3=$rowplus['lname'];
    $email=$_SESSION['email'];
}

if ($email==$email3)
{
    echo "UNPLUS";
}
else
{
    echo "PLUS";
}
```

In this code, if the last row inserted has $email=$email3 then the if command executes successfully and it prints UNPLUS, but if $email=$email3 is true in any other row than the last row, the command fails to execute and prints the PLUS.

Please tell me what's wrong in it.

NOTE: $_SESSION['email'] is the value of the email field of another table which has the value provided by the user who is logged in at the moment.

Comment: Any why don't you let the SQL request do the comparison and just check for a return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$queryplus="SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."' and email='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['email']."' and comment='plus'";
```

Comment: not exactly by your answer, but I got a hint about what should I do by your answer and get rid of the trouble...

Answer (score 5):

Your `while()` is fetching all the rows and assigning them to variables... and then not doing anything with that data, until AFTER the loop finishes. This means that you're fetching however many rows, and THROWING AWAY all but the last row's data.

You need to move your `if ($email ...)` check inside the while() loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultplus) {
   ... assign variables ...
   if ($email == $email3) {
      yada yada
   } else {
      yada yada
   }
}
```

Comment: if I do so, it prints out all the rows which I use in echo... e.g. if I print out echo $email3; then it shows all the emails...